# How to make ODBC connection in web.Config file

Tags: crystal-reports, odbc

I was to make crystal reporting with sybase database. I will use reportviewer to view those report. I am stuck on how to make ODBC connection in web.config file.

I had done with winforms but I am still learning.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at connectionstrings.com: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sybase-advantage and http://www.connectionstrings.com/sybase-adaptive